# Problem with setting the orientation of the image

Tags: android, camera, photo

Is my second question on this topic today but on the previous one it seems I haven't been clear enough.

I have an activity where I'm building my own camera in order to take pictures.
In the `onCreate()` method of this activity I'm doing something like:

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

otherwise my whole screen looks like this:
.Anyway this solves my issues for the moment and the image is looking good.

After taking the picture I'm using a bundle and send the image to another activity(Activity B) where I edit the picture and after that save the image to a website.

And here is the problem:
The picture received in this activity is again orientated wrong like here: 
![enter image description here][1]  because I haven't done any operations upon the image itself, only on the activity orientation.

Now, I could do in here barely the same thing and set the activity in the `LANDSCAPE` mode and my activity would be looking good again, but further more when I upload the image to a website this would look wrong on the website for the simple fact that I haven't done anything to set her own orietntation.

So, in my `surfaceChanged()` - in the `activity A` , the first one, method I've done something like this:

```
Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
 p.set("orientation", "landscape");
 p.setRotation(90);
 mCamera.setParameters(p);
```

But this has no effect on the image, it looks the same.

I'm working on `Sony Ericsson` and need help on rotating my image-not setting up the `orientation of my activity`!

Thank you, I'm here for further details.Thanks

EDIT:
In `activity A` where I'm taking the image I'm doing this:

```
Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback(){
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {

            if (imageData != null) {

                Intent mIntent = new Intent();

                //StoreByteImage(mContext, imageData, 50, "ImageName");
                mCamera.startPreview();

                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putByteArray("imageData", imageData);
                Intent i = new Intent(mContext,ImageDisplayActivity.class);
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);

                setResult(FOTO_MODE, mIntent);
                finish();

            }
        }
    };
```

And in `activity B` where I'm receiving the image I'm doing this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 5;
        byte[] imageData = extras.getByteArray("imageData");
        Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData , 0, imageData.length,options);
....///is set up the bitmap to an imageview
```

Comment: `I'm using a bundle and send the image to another activity(Activity B)` sho me the `bundle` code

Comment: Actually All i want to know is `is the image a Bitmap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I have a hunch that you are overestimating the problem!

Try to rotate `myImage` before uploading

```
Matrix mat = new Matrix();
mat.postRotate(90);
image_to_upload = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImage, 0, 0, myImage.getWidth(), myImage.getHeight(), mat, true);
```

Try different angles I am sure this is the issue and you will find the right path

Comment: I might overestimating it but I can take it anymore.My post might sound a little bit dramatic but I'll get over it once this works!

Comment: Yes and it's working:D...but I'm facing another issue-I cannot make it to look full screen:)

Comment: just ask and dont forget to put `android` as tag! I will try to help